# Взаимосвязь при работе с базой между HIbernate и Spring Data

Tags: hibernate, spring-data

Добрый день!

Вопрос следующего рода: если я правильно понимаю, мы можем работать с базой данных, используя лишь entity, который размечен аннотациями, и не размечая SQL запросами repository слой. К примеру, вот так:
[image: entity] 
Но в одном Spring приложении, я увидел также класс из репозиторий - слоя, который имеет такой вот вид, в котором меня смущают SQL запросы:
[image: repo]
Так вот: зачем одновременно размечать entity аннотациями и писать SQL запросы в repository слое? Возможно ли одно без другого? Как они взаимосвязаны? Какие best practises вы могли бы посоветовать?

P.S.: Извините, если вопрос показался вам глупым, но я действительно не могу найти внятный и всеобъемлющий ответ на него.

Comment: Вопрос нормальный, но лучше картинки заменить текстом.

Comment: Спасибо! А почему заменить? Мне казалось что наоборот, так будет нагляднее.

Comment: С телефона плохо видно, что за код там. Всегда вставляйте код текстом. https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4692

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Цитата из [документации](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#jpa.query-methods.at-query):

> Using named queries to declare queries for entities is a valid
>   approach and works fine for a small number of queries. As the queries
>   themselves are tied to the Java method that executes them you actually
>   can bind them directly using the Spring Data JPA @Query annotation
>   rather than annotating them to the domain class. This will free the
>   domain class from persistence specific information and co-locate the
>   query to the repository interface.
>
> Queries annotated to the query method will take precedence over
>   queries defined using @NamedQuery or named queries declared in
>   orm.xml.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
>
>   @Query("select u from User u where u.emailAddress = ?1")
>   User findByEmailAddress(String emailAddress);
> }
> ```

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/173419)

Comment: Спасибо за совет, сейчас исправлю.